# Can I continue booting into Ubuntu if I move my drive to another laptop?

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu on an SSD on one laptop, but just purchased a new laptop. Will I be able to put the SSD in the new laptop and still boot fine, or is the install hardware dependent? I know with Windows I had trouble doing this before.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it with desktop machines and it worked fine.

You need to make sure the new device supports Ubuntu (you can test with a liveCD/usb stick).

You may get complications with display drivers and wifi drivers if they were not automagically configured by default (you had to manually configure/install).

Answer (score 1):

It is best if you know that other computer does not use the same video card driver to remove the driver before you remove the SSD from the computer it is in now, otherwise it will most likely not boot.

With the video card driver removed from the computer it was in before installing it into the new one will let the ubuntu load the generic video card driver when it first boots in the new computer.

As for wifi driver and sound card driver they can be dealt with once it is in the new computer.

I have done this myself three times with computer with totally different specification and never had any issues as long as I removed video card driver while it is still in the first computer then after it is in the second computer install the video card driver for that computer unless it is intel and then the driver should be installed already.